# getting bad input from dirty buffer

Tags: c, sockets, buffer

Essentially I have am simulating a TCP connection with sockets and I am sending information between client and server between sockets. I want to use a single buffer for each file, but unfortunately when writing, it overwrites the buffer getting a bad/dirty string in line (B) with buffer containing something like `noexistshed`, the `hed` part, obviously being a remnant of `Established` from a previous message written.
At first the client prints `Connection Status: Established` just fine, but later on, because of this dirty buffer, the printf in line (C), prints `1`, since "noexistshed" and "noexist" are different.

All buffers are declared as `char buffer[1024];`. Similarly user and pass are defined as `char user[80]` and `char pass[80]`, (although I am seeking to make these 2 a single buffer).

This is the problematic section of the client:

```
read(clientSocket, buffer, 1024);

  /*---- Print the received message ----*/
  printf("Connection Status: %s\n", buffer);   

  printf("Please enter a username:\n");
  scanf ("%s", user);

  write(clientSocket, user, strlen(user)+1);

  read(clientSocket, buffer, 80); // error happens here -- (B)

  printf("%s comparison result %d", buffer, strcmp(buffer, "noexists")); // --- (C)

  if(strcmp(buffer, "noexists") == 0)
  {
  printf("User doesn't exist\n");
    exit(1);
  }
```

This is the problematic section of the server:

```
  strcpy(buffer,"Established.");
  write(senderSocket,buffer,13,0);

  memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer)); // ---- (A)

  read(senderSocket, buffer, 80, 0);

  int x;
  for(x=0; x < 7 && strcmp(ul[0][0], buffer) != 0; x++);

  printf("%d", x);

  if(x == 7)
  {
    strcpy(buffer,"noexists");
  } else {
    strcpy(buffer,"exists");
  }

  write(senderSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);

  read(senderSocket, buffer, 80, 0);
```

line (A) is what I presume might be the solution to my problems from what I have read in other questions/sites, but it is not working. I have also tried replacing it with `buffer[0] = '\0';` and `buffer[n] = '\0';` (with n being assigned the value of the read/write) with no luck. Also I've tried putting it after/before writes and reads, but there are just so many permutations that can be done, that I don't think I can solve it on my own. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You're missing the NUL terminator somewhere. `strlen` only works with NUL terminated strings.

Comment: ^^ yup, if it's C network code with str* in it, it's almost certainly wrong:(

Comment: I'd say the problem is the `write` in the server using `strlen(buffer)` instead of `strlen(buffer)+1`. Note that you have the `+1` on the client side, but not the server side.

Comment: To start with, ignoring the result returned by read() is always wrong.  That result, if >0, is the ONLY way to determine how many bytes have been loaded into the buffer, quite apart from the meaning of zero and negative values.

Comment: 'memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));' is cargo-cult rubbish. Use the result returned by read() to insert a null, (assuming you need one, ie. you are not transferring non-text data with embedded nulls).

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, like I said, I tried implementing `buffer[n] = '\0';` (with n being equal to the value of the read) on the code, but after trying so many ways I took it out back to the vanilla version.

Comment: Next - the TCP stream service cannot transfer any messages longer than one byte.   Assuming differently is always wrong, which is why there are so many protocols on top of TCP to transfer longer messages, eg. HTTP.

Comment: Put another way, even assuming no error or connection close, (which you do not check for), sending 'noexists' at one end can result a single peer read call loading either n, no, noe, noex, noexi, noexis, noexist or noexists into the buffer.

Comment: @MartinJames you might be very right. I semi-fixed my issue by adding `buffer[n] = '\0';` right after every `read()` (although I fail to comprehend why I should), however I am experiencing wild behavior, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I guess because of what you said. How can I avoid this?

Comment: You need to capture the return value from `read()` so you know how many bytes were received.  The data won't be null terminated unless you wrote a null terminator on the socket.